# C Programming : Sum of third upper anti-diagonal a squared matrix , help badly needed please

Tags: c, matrix

im doing a short course in c programming and i have been so busy lately with my other classes and and helping my bother prepare for his wedding (as im his best man)that I have fallen behind and need help. any help towards this short assignment would be much appreciated as im not familiar at all with matrixs and its due in a few days.

the assignment is to Sum of third upper anti-diagonal a squared matrix .

i have been given this information:

The matrix should be a square, integer matrix of size N. In this assignment the matrix will be stored
in a 1d block of memory. You will have to convert between the conceptual 2d matrix addressing and
1d block addressing with pointer arithmetic.

Note on random numbers:
`rand()` function returns the next integer a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range
[0, `RAND_MAX`]. `RAND_MAX` is a very large number and varies from system to system. To get an
integer in the range [min, max]:

```
(int)((min)+rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0) * ((max)-(min)+1))
```

`srand(SEED)` is used to set the seed for rand. If `srand()` is called with the same seed value, the
sequence of pseudo-random numbers is repeated. To get different random numbers each time a
programme runs use `time(NULL)` as the seed. Rand is in `stdlib.h`, which needs to be included.

The program should be structured as follows.

```
#define N 32 // Matrix size

#define MYSEED 1234 // Last 4 digits of your student number.

int *initialise( )        // Allocate memory for the matrix using malloc
                           // Initialise the matrix with random integers x, 1≤ x ≤ 9
                           // Use 'MYSEED' as the seed in the random generator.
                           // Return a pointer to the matrix

void print_matrix(int *)      // Print matrix on screen

int compute_diagonal(int *)   // Compute your required calculation using pointer arithmetic.
                              // (square bracket [ ] array indexes shouldn't be used)
                              // Return the solution.

void finalise(int *)          //free the allocated memory.

int main()                    // The main function should print the solution to screen.
```

Comment: You should at least take the time to do a little be more than simply pasting the assignment text here. You could, for example, format the code.

Comment: "...i have been so busy lately with my other classes and and helping my bother prepare for his wedding..." - none of this is our concern.  This isn't a homework help service.  Post some code and ask specific questions if you have any when you run into trouble.  Were you planning to inform your professor if someone posted code that wasn't yours?

Comment: Bob, do you have a more specific question? A lot of S.O. users feel rather insulted when someone comes and asks directly for a solution to their problem without demonstrating what they've tried so far.  (There's an anti-homework bias; questions about specific problems within an assignment aren't problematic, it's questions asking for solutions that get S.O.-ers ruffled).  If you tried something I'd encourage you to show it.  Then to ask specific questions you're stuck on like: "How do I compute the initial size I need for malloc?"

Comment: i apologise for my indescretion i just thought i could get a little bit of help or a clue where to start sorry if i came across as rude.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing your homework assignment for you, here's a tip:

Make a functions that abstract storing and retrieving values out of the matrix.  One of the signatures should look a lot like this:

```
int retrieve(int* matrix, int row, int col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok since this is homework and you still have a few days I will not give you an exact answer here. But I will give you some thoughts with which it should be pretty easy to come to your answer.

1. Indexing a matrix 1D-way: You are not allowed to use `matrix[x][y]` here, but only a one-dimensional array. So just take a minute and think of how the index (x,y) can be computed within a 1D array. Keep in mind that C stores elements rowwise (i.e. the elements `matrix[0][0]`, `matrix[0][1]`, `matrix[0][2]` refer to `matrix[0]`, `matrix[1]`, `matrix[2]`). It is a simply forumla in terms of X, Y and N
2. Filling the matrix randomly is easy, the function to create a random int is already given, just walk the matrix along and fill every element
3. Adding the third anti-upper diagonal. This isn really a programming question. Just sketch a small matrix on a piece of paper and see what elements you have to add. Look at their indices and than combine your newly gained knowledge with your result from my point 1 and you will know what to add up

Edit: Since you are not allowed to use the bracket operator, keep in mind that `matrix[5]` is the same as `*(matrix+5)`.
I think it's fair to tell you this ;)

Comment: thanks alot chris i really appreciate the help and that you didnt just give out to me for posting this .im going get started straight away i just needed a starting point . thanks again for helping me in a tight spot  .